# Sed Regular expression that get data between rx: and [space]

Tags: regex, sed

I have this expression that take everything

```
local RX=`sed -e 's#.*rx:\(\)#\1#' <<< "${LINE}"`
```

The variable `LINE` has as content:

```
4: uart:PL011 rev3 mmio:0xC006D000 irq:26 tx:435 rx:0 RTS|DTR
```

What I want is returning rx value, in this case, 0

Right now, it is returing everything after "rx:"

How should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may extract all digits after `rx:` using

```
RX=`sed -e 's#.*rx:\([0-9]*\).*#\1#' <<< "${LINE}"`
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/EwntoB)

I added `[0-9]*` between `\(\)` to match 0 or more digits and also a `.*` pattern at the end of the regex to consume the rest of the line, so that in the output, you could have just the value captured in Group 1.

To match any chars other than whitespace replace `[0-9]` with `[^[:space:]]` or `[^[:blank:]]`, or even `[^ ]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can change to this:

```
local RX=`sed -e 's#.*rx:\([^ ]*\).*#\1#' <<< "${LINE}"`
```

But in this case, if you can use `GNU grep` then it's better:

```
local RX=`grep -oP 'rx:\K[^ ]*' <<< "${LINE}"`
```

They're to capture things after `rx:` and before the space.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach:

```
$ awk -v tag='rx' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){ split($i,t,/:/); f[t[1]]=t[2] } print f[tag]}' <<<"$line"
0

$ awk -v tag='mmio' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){ split($i,t,/:/); f[t[1]]=t[2] } print f[tag]}' <<<"$line"
0xC006D000

$ awk -v tag='uart' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){ split($i,t,/:/); f[t[1]]=t[2] } print f[tag]}' <<<"$line"
PL011
```

Given that you can simply print individual or as many values as you like.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following too.

```
awk '
match($0,/rx[^ ]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/.*:/,"",val)
  print val
  val=""
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: @Juliatzin del Toro, could you please check this solution once if this helps you?